# Error while uploading app on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have created an app using shiny. It allows the user to upload a data set do calculations and visualization on it and then download the finished output in csv form. The app is running smoothly when run locally from my PC. However when I am trying to upload it, it is throwing an error. I have attached below the log as I am unable to interpret it properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading application bundle...DONE
Deploying application: 30310...
Waiting for task: 4614482
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building package: KFAS
  building: Building package: rucm
  building: Installing packages
  error: Installing files
################################## Begin Log ################################## 
[2015-01-27T09:37:02.321076276+0000] Installing R package: xtable (1.7-4)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �xtable� ...
* DONE (xtable)
[2015-01-27T09:37:02.653602561+0000] Installing R package: magrittr (1.0.1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �magrittr� ...
* DONE (magrittr)
[2015-01-27T09:37:02.943212197+0000] Installing R package: stringr (0.6.2)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �stringr� ...
* DONE (stringr)
[2015-01-27T09:37:03.235246418+0000] Installing R package: assertthat (0.1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �assertthat� ...
* DONE (assertthat)
[2015-01-27T09:37:03.504695427+0000] Installing R package: R6 (2.0.1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �R6� ...
* DONE (R6)
[2015-01-27T09:37:03.804570827+0000] Installing R package: lazyeval (0.1.9)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �lazyeval� ...
* DONE (lazyeval)
[2015-01-27T09:37:04.091068822+0000] Building R package: KFAS (1.0.4-1)
/mnt/packages/build /mnt
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *source* package �KFAS� ...
** package �KFAS� successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  approx.f95 -o approx.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  artransform.f95 -o artransform.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  covmeanw.f95 -o covmeanw.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  deviance.f95 -o deviance.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  filtersimfast.f95 -o filtersimfast.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  gloglik.f95 -o gloglik.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  glogliku.f95 -o glogliku.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  gsmoothall.f95 -o gsmoothall.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  isample.f95 -o isample.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  isamplefilter.f95 -o isamplefilter.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  kfilter.f95 -o kfilter.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  kfstheta.f95 -o kfstheta.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  ldl.f95 -o ldl.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  ldlssm.f95 -o ldlssm.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  ngfilter.f95 -o ngfilter.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  ngloglik.f95 -o ngloglik.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  ngsmooth.f95 -o ngsmooth.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  predict.f95 -o predict.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  simfilter.f95 -o simfilter.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  simgaussian.f95 -o simgaussian.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  smoothsim.f95 -o smoothsim.o
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2  -c  smoothsimfast.f95 -o smoothsimfast.o
gfortran -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o KFAS.so approx.o artransform.o covmeanw.o deviance.o filtersimfast.o gloglik.o glogliku.o gsmoothall.o init.o isample.o isamplefilter.o kfilter.o kfstheta.o ldl.o ldlssm.o ngfilter.o ngloglik.o ngsmooth.o predict.o simfilter.o simgaussian.o smoothsim.o smoothsimfast.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/KFAS/libs
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* creating tarball
packaged installation of �KFAS� as �KFAS_1.0.4-1_R_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz�
* DONE (KFAS)
/mnt
[2015-01-27T09:37:08.541023340+0000] Building R package: rucm (0.4)
/mnt/packages/build /mnt
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *source* package �rucm� ...
** package �rucm� successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* creating tarball
packaged installation of �rucm� as �rucm_0.4_R_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz�
* DONE (rucm)
/mnt
[2015-01-27T09:37:09.612899728+0000] Installing R package: digest (0.6.4)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �digest� ...
* DONE (digest)
[2015-01-27T09:37:09.940209749+0000] Installing R package: memoise (0.2.1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �memoise� ...
* DONE (memoise)
[2015-01-27T09:37:10.215472054+0000] Installing R package: mime (0.2)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �mime� ...
* DONE (mime)
[2015-01-27T09:37:10.484427902+0000] Installing R package: BH (1.54.0-5)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �BH� ...
* DONE (BH)
[2015-01-27T09:37:22.958534096+0000] Installing R package: htmltools (0.2.6)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �htmltools� ...
* DONE (htmltools)
[2015-01-27T09:37:23.239249976+0000] Installing R package: DBI (0.3.1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �DBI� ...
* DONE (DBI)
[2015-01-27T09:37:23.520219717+0000] Installing R package: RJSONIO (1.3-0)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �RJSONIO� ...
* DONE (RJSONIO)
[2015-01-27T09:37:23.987844195+0000] Installing R package: Rcpp (0.11.3)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �Rcpp� ...
* DONE (Rcpp)
[2015-01-27T09:37:25.448919075+0000] Installing R package: plyr (1.8.1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �plyr� ...
* DONE (plyr)
[2015-01-27T09:37:25.826508960+0000] Installing R package: reshape2 (1.4)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �reshape2� ...
* DONE (reshape2)
[2015-01-27T09:37:26.139563516+0000] Installing R package: lubridate (1.3.3)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �lubridate� ...
* DONE (lubridate)
[2015-01-27T09:37:26.500520798+0000] Installing R package: httpuv (1.3.2)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �httpuv� ...
* DONE (httpuv)
[2015-01-27T09:37:26.918339752+0000] Installing R package: shiny (0.10.2.1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �shiny� ...
* DONE (shiny)
[2015-01-27T09:37:27.609392478+0000] Installing R package: shinyTable (0.1.0)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �shinyTable� ...
* DONE (shinyTable)
[2015-01-27T09:37:27.928101202+0000] Installing R package: googleVis (0.5.8)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �googleVis� ...
* DONE (googleVis)
[2015-01-27T09:37:28.257805835+0000] Installing R package: dplyr (0.3.0.2)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �dplyr� ...
* DONE (dplyr)
[2015-01-27T09:37:30.042679916+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/Handset_Modelling
[2015-01-27T09:37:30.051513234+0000] Copying file ui.R
[2015-01-27T09:37:30.060322563+0000] Copying file server.R
################################### End Log ################################### 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 4614483 error: Unhandled Exception: Mktemp failed: mkdir /mnt/docker/graph/_tmp/193b0da996c3296fb4bdef59f91d8b52a441bb0cc56ef31727f74bbfc9822972: too many links
Execution halted
```

Comment: `too many links` looks that deploy can't tar(zip) your directory since you have too many files. Try to reduce your directory numbe. Maybe related to  [this](http://superuser.com/questions/298420/cannot-mkdir-too-many-links)

Comment: At a given point of time the app needs 1 csv file as input to generate 7 csv files which can be downloaded as output. Do you think this can be bypassed if I zip all the 7 csv files so that they can be downloaded at a click instead of the current option of letting the user download each of the 7 files one by one?